# Understanding hexadecimal output from C pointers

Tags: c, pointers, hex

I ran some C code in CodeBlocks and printed the memory address.  The result was a 16 character hexadecimal.  This was an exercise in the youtube tutorial on C from freeCodeCamp at 3:14:05.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJgsSFOSQv0&list=FLWOrEQtSUgIDNHMCI3yfvnQ&index=4
The youtube presenter came up with an 8 character hexadecimal result.  Does this mean I have twice the system ram vs the presenter?  My Windows 10 laptop has 32 GB of ram.

Edit, I was instructed to post the relevant C code, here it is.
int main()
{

```
int age = 30;
int * pAge = &age;
double gpa = 3.4;
double * pGpa = &gpa;
char grade = 'A';
char * pGrade = &grade;



printf("age's memory address: %p\n", &age);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Those are virtual addresses not physical addresses. It says nothing about the amount of RAM/physical memory.

Comment: You need to post the relevant code here on this site as text.

Comment: A question should be self contained and not only be a pointer to some external resource

Comment: The output with `%p` depends on the platform and on the size of a pointer on the platform. On a 32 bit platform you'll get most likely something like `00ea1252`, on a 64 bit platform you'll get most likely something like `00048a7b00051252`. So basically that means that the presenter's is on a 32 bit platform and you're on a 64 bit platform.

Comment: You need to reflect on your intuitions. If a number X has twice as many digits as number Y, that doesn't mean that its magnitude is twice as great. 200 is twice 100, but they require the same number of digits. A six-digit number could be as big as 999,999, and a three-digit number is less than a thousand. So with six digits, you can express a lot more than twice as many possibilities. This is one of the classic fast thinking/slow thinking bugs, q.v. Daniel Kahnemann.

Answer (score 0):

Older Windows versions had a 32 bit address bus. Newer versions support 64 bit data access and 64 bit address buses (given that the CPU is 64 bit too). It has absolutely nothing to do with how much physical RAM you have. Although it was problematic to expand old PC:s beyond 4GB of addressable memory, which was one of the main reasons for migrating to 64 bit.